# How to scan an a txt within the same package?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to use Java.util.scanner on a txt to parse it. I am having trouble trying to scan the file because the file isn't found.

My class is within the same package of the txt file. So can you please tell me how to scan a file within the same package of the class.

```
public class PhoneBook {
  private ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry>[] buckets;
  public void load() {
    try {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("phone.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("File Not Found"); 
    } 
  } 
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    PhoneBook phone = new PhoneBook(); 
    phone.load(); 
  } 
}
```

Here is the StackTrace of the error

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: phone.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at HashSet.PhoneBook.load(PhoneBook.java:13)
        at HashSet.PhoneBook.main(PhoneBook.java:23)`

Comment: What does `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` print?

Comment: You need to specify you path to the file. If you just specify your file name the default folder will be the "bin" folder or the folder where your classfile is located.

Comment: @Prasanth Please add the code to the question - its very hard to read in the comment

Comment: the file is inside the folder where the class file is located

Comment: @Prasanth Use the edit function !

Comment: You can use e.printStackTrace() to see an more detailed error message

Comment: `package HashSet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneBook {
 private ArrayList<PhoneBookEntry>[] buckets;
 public void load()
 {
  try {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("phone.txt"));
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
   System.out.println("File Not Found");
  }
 }
 public static void main(String[]args)
 {
  PhoneBook phone = new PhoneBook();
  phone.load();
 }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the file in the root of your class path (after compilation, your file should appear in the root folder where `.class` files are generated) and use the code syntax below:

```
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("phone.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(is);
```

Comment: Do I have to use try and catch; if so what do I catch?

Comment: @Prasanth There is no checked exception in picture so it's up to you. If you want, you want to perform the standard Exception scenario Handling e.g. null check.

Answer (score 1):

```
new File("phone.txt")
```

looks up the file in the current working directory. This is the directory where you started the java virtual machine.

You say that it is located in the same package as the class, which is most likely a different directory (e.g. `src/com/mypackage`).

Try moving the file to the root directory of your project. You should then be able to load it.

A different approach is shown in the answer from @Yogendra, which should work also when the file is located in the same package binary directory as your `.class` file. But I am not sure if you want to load this kind of file as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in one of the comments, you need to put the file where the .jar is generated. If you're running from Netbeans/Eclipse, this will be the root folder of your project, if you're running from the compiled .jar, it will be the same directory as the .jar. Packages are only folders used to organise and separate source files.

But if you want to have the file in the same package anyway, you can always do something like (presuming you only have one package):

```
new File("./src/myPackage/myFile.txt")
```